# Samba server mount error - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, mount, samba

I have Samba server running on my VM and try to connect on it from my workstation, but i still get errors.

**Samba smb.conf :**

```
[sam]
comment = samba
path = /smb
write list = samba root
```

**Server:**

```
samba version : 4.8.3
OS version : CentOs 7
```

**Client:**

```
samba version : 4.9.1
OS version : Red Hat Enterprise 7.7
```

**Mount command :**

> mount -t cifs //192.168.122.78/smb /samba -o username=samba,password=password,vers=2.1

**Direct error after command exec :**

> mount error(2): No such file or directory

**Error in /var/log/messages on client :**

```
Sep 12 08:12:22 oc8211134760 kernel: CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\192.168.122.78\smb
Sep 12 08:12:22 oc8211134760 kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

When i try to execute mount command with older version of samba, 1.0 the direct error is little bit different.

> mount error(6): No such device or address

I was trying to find solution, but it looks like some common problem with versions of samba? Could it be because of different versions on Server/Client? And also i am little bit confused what is different between SMB protocol version i set in my mount command (vers=2.1/1.0) and the official version what command `smbstatus` is giving me (4.9.1).

Have anybody some ideas how can i solve this problem please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Share Name is "sam".

Try:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.122.78/sam /samba -o username=samba,password=password,vers=2.1
```

Comment: No way... I am stupid, thought i have to specified directory, not the name... Thanks a lot